# How to fix Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, core-location, fatal-error, crashlytics

Version mismatch failure when trying to persist (update) the identity object (persistIdentity:error:). Object version=1229, persisted version=1230.

```
#10. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  AppName                         0x1032b983c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309293116
1  AppName                         0x1032b983c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309293116
2  AppName                         0x1032b96f8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309292792
3  AppName                         0x1032a9814 CLSHandler + 4309227540
4  AppName                         0x1032b7844 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4309284932
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x184025640 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  AppName                         0x1032b72d8 CLSExceptionRecord + 4309283544
8  AppName                         0x1032b7100 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4309283072
9  AppName                         0x1032b6d14 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4309282068
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1838d537c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1838d4ccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 130
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1838e4720 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 362
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18472ac6c -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 114
14 LayerKit                       0x104eb4bf4 __47-[LYRIdentityRepository persistIdentity:error:]_block_invoke + 3760
15 LayerKit                       0x104eb0ff8 -[LYRIdentityRepository attemptBlock:] + 24
16 LayerKit                       0x104eb3bd8 -[LYRIdentityRepository persistIdentity:error:] + 468
17 LayerKit                       0x104eab904 __59-[LYRIdentity setPresenceStatusAndPostObjectChanges:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 212
18 LayerKit                       0x104e6dfb4 -[LYRDatabaseTransaction executeTransactionUsingBlock:completion:] + 116
19 LayerKit                       0x104eab7c4 __59-[LYRIdentity setPresenceStatusAndPostObjectChanges:error:]_block_invoke + 312
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cb24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x184026a38 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

--

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18472ad8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1838e45ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18472ac6c -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  LayerKit                       0x104eb4bf4 (Missing)
4  LayerKit                       0x104eb0ff8 (Missing)
5  LayerKit                       0x104eb3bd8 (Missing)
6  LayerKit                       0x104eab904 (Missing)
7  LayerKit                       0x104e6dfb4 (Missing)
8  LayerKit                       0x104eab7c4 (Missing)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cb24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x184026a38 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread

#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1064d9a38 swift_getInitializedObjCClass + 58
1  CoreFoundation                 0x184732580 __invoking___ + 144
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184611748 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18461656c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
4  AppName                         0x103791134 -[LLAppDelegateProxy forwardInvocation:] (LLAppDelegateProxy.m:68)
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1847302d4 ___forwarding___ + 624
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18461641c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
7  UIKit                          0x18e6b4510 -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] + 172
8  UIKit                          0x18e2c5e10 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1388
9  UIKit                          0x18ef5b72c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296
10 UIKit                          0x18e2c5268 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432
11 UIKit                          0x18ed409b8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
12 UIKit                          0x18ee8eae8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
13 UIKit                          0x18e2c4c88 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248
14 UIKit                          0x18e2c4624 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368
15 UIKit                          0x18e3023b0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 468
16 FrontBoardServices             0x186f28f24 __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 + 212
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840241f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
19 FrontBoardServices             0x186f5c878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
20 FrontBoardServices             0x186f5c51c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
21 FrontBoardServices             0x186f5cab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1846d3404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1846d2c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1846d079c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1845f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
26 GraphicsServices               0x1865d3020 GSEventRunModal + 100
27 UIKit                          0x18e5d178c UIApplicationMain + 236
28 AppName                         0x1027a698c main (AppDelegate.swift:21)
29 libdyld.dylib                  0x184081fc0 start + 4

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fc80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d2e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d0908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1845f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x185065674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x18506551c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7  UIKit                          0x18e2b67e4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x185175efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#2. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fc80 mach_msg + 72
2  AppName                         0x1032a46e4 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4309206756
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#3. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fc80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d2e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d0908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1845f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x184efe4b0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x185175efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#4. com.apple.CFNetwork.CustomProtocols
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fc80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d2e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d0908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1845f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x184efe4b0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x185175efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#5. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1538 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1846db378 __CFSocketManager + 644
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#6. com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fc80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d2e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1846d0908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1845f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x185065674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  AppName                         0x1033ffd30 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] + 4310629680
7  Foundation                     0x185175efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351220 _pthread_body + 272
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184351110 _pthread_body + 290
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb10 thread_start + 4

#7. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb04 start_wqthread + 122

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#10. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  AppName                         0x1032b983c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309293116
1  AppName                         0x1032b983c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309293116
2  AppName                         0x1032b96f8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4309292792
3  AppName                         0x1032a9814 CLSHandler + 4309227540
4  AppName                         0x1032b7844 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4309284932
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x184025640 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  AppName                         0x1032b72d8 CLSExceptionRecord + 4309283544
8  AppName                         0x1032b7100 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4309283072
9  AppName                         0x1032b6d14 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4309282068
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1838d537c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1838d4ccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 130
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1838e4720 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 362
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18472ac6c -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 114
14 LayerKit                       0x104eb4bf4 __47-[LYRIdentityRepository persistIdentity:error:]_block_invoke + 3760
15 LayerKit                       0x104eb0ff8 -[LYRIdentityRepository attemptBlock:] + 24
16 LayerKit                       0x104eb3bd8 -[LYRIdentityRepository persistIdentity:error:] + 468
17 LayerKit                       0x104eab904 __59-[LYRIdentity setPresenceStatusAndPostObjectChanges:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 212
18 LayerKit                       0x104e6dfb4 -[LYRDatabaseTransaction executeTransactionUsingBlock:completion:] + 116
19 LayerKit                       0x104eab7c4 __59-[LYRIdentity setPresenceStatusAndPostObjectChanges:error:]_block_invoke + 312
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cb24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x184026a38 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#11. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c032a460.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f0b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3  CoreLocation                   0x18ae9c888 CLClientInvalidate + 888
4  CoreLocation                   0x18aea2878 CLClientRetrieveData + 2828
5  CoreLocation                   0x18aef8b18 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 79496
6  CoreLocation                   0x18aef4bf0 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 63328
7  CoreLocation                   0x18aef6390 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 69376
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438b220 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f19c do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 160
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f0c8 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 80
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f04c notify_server + 92
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x1843956b0 _xpc_connection_pass2mig + 164
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x184388c14 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1080
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cbb4 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840334c4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x184033f70 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 508
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#12. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c4322b20.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f0b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3  CoreLocation                   0x18ae9c888 CLClientInvalidate + 888
4  CoreLocation                   0x18aea2878 CLClientRetrieveData + 2828
5  CoreLocation                   0x18aef8b18 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 79496
6  CoreLocation                   0x18aef4bf0 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 63328
7  CoreLocation                   0x18aef6390 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 69376
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438b220 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f19c do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 160
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f0c8 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 80
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f04c notify_server + 92
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x1843956b0 _xpc_connection_pass2mig + 164
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x184388c14 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1080
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cbb4 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840334c4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x184033f70 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 508
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#13. com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c0324ec0.events
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18418fe5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f0b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18401f924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3  CoreLocation                   0x18ae9c888 CLClientInvalidate + 888
4  CoreLocation                   0x18aea2878 CLClientRetrieveData + 2828
5  CoreLocation                   0x18aef8b18 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 79496
6  CoreLocation                   0x18aef4bf0 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 63328
7  CoreLocation                   0x18aef6390 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 69376
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438b220 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f19c do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 160
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f0c8 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 80
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x18438f04c notify_server + 92
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x1843956b0 _xpc_connection_pass2mig + 164
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x184388c14 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1080
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18401cbb4 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840334c4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x184033f70 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 508
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1840268f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x184027d4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x18403011c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#14. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#15. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb04 start_wqthread + 122

#16. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#17. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#18. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4

#19. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1841b1d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434feb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18434fb08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Corelocation is mentioned in the thread. 53% of the crashes happen in  the background. Makes me think that has something to do with live tracking the user while they are out of the app.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a crash in layer SDK and has been fixed in Layerkit 4.0.4
Simply updating the layer 4.0.4 resolved the problem.